# What does "that of" stand for in a comparative sentence?

Tags: american-english, possessives

What is the difference between

> My skill is better than that of Tony's.

and

> My skill is better than Tony's.

When to omit or add this "that of"?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is incorrect. Adding "that of" indicates possession, so you don't need to use "Tony's" but instead just "Tony." However, it is an unconventional construction to use with a person as the possessor.

Basically, you should use one or the other, not both. "That of" in this usage is just another way to indicate possession, so apostrophe + s is unnecessary.